# Hint to show $\frac{1}{n^2-n+1} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Looking for a hint as to show the following inequality. I know it should be relatively simple but I just don't see it. I apologise as I'm aware it's rather basic, but I'm getting frustrated.

I'm reading an example concerning the proof of convergence of the following series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-n+1} $$
using a comparison with a series I know converges, naimley $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2}$.

For this to work i need to show
$$ \frac{1}{n^2-n+1} \leq \frac{2}{n^2} $$

Algebraic manipulation hasn't gotten me anywhere so far. The subtraction of $n$ in the denominator is what's giving me issues I think. Many thanks.

Comment: Yep. Apologies corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\ge 1$ the denominators are positive, so the inequality

$$\frac1{n^2-n+1}\le\frac2{n^2}$$

is equivalent to the inequality

$$n^2\le 2(n^2-n+1)\,,$$

which in turn is equivalent to $0\le n^2-2n+2$. Now think of the righthand side as $(n^2-2n+1)+1$ and rewrite it in a way that makes clear that it really is non-negative.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$n^2 - 2n + 2 = (n^2 - 2n + 1) + 1 = (n-1)^2 + 1 > 0$$ so that
$$2(n^2 - n + 1) = 2n^2 - 2n + 2 > n^2.$$
In particular $n^2 - n + 1 > 0$, and you may divide both sides by $n^2(n^2 - n + 1)$ to get
$$\frac{2}{n^2} > \frac{1}{n^2 - n + 1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here a direct way for $n>1$:

$$\frac 1{n^2-n+1}\leq \frac 1{n(n-1)}=\frac n{n-1}\cdot\frac 1{n^2}=\left(1+\frac 1{n-1}\right)\frac 1{n^2}\leq \frac 2{n^2}$$

For $n=1$ the inequality $\frac 1{n^2-n+1}\leq\frac 2{n^2}$ holds obviously, as well.